# php $GLOBALS show undefined "_SERVER"

Tags: php, arrays, variables, global

I am currently working on a php framework and in it I have to store the variables of `$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc...

BUT when I call `$GLOBALS["_SERVER"]` I get undefined index error. That is not possible because `$_SERVER` is a predefined variable.. right?

But when I call `$_SERVER` at the beginning of the code `$GLOBALS["_SERVER"]` is defined.

You all have got it wrong I want to use $GLOBALS because of the following classes,

```
    class Base_Infrastructure{
    function __construct(){
        $name = '_'.strtoupper(str_replace(__NAMESPACE__."\\","",get_called_class()));
        foreach($GLOBALS[$name] as $i => $v){
            $this->{$i} = $v;
        }
    }
    private function dispatch(){
        $name = '_'.strtoupper(str_replace(__NAMESPACE__."\\","",get_called_class()));
        $GLOBALS[$name] = $this;
        return true;
    }
    function get($name){
        if(isset($this->{$name})&&!empty($this->{$name})){
            return $this->{$name};
        }
    }
    function set($name,$value){
        $this->{$name} = $value;
        $this->dispatch();
        return true;
    }
    function remove($name){
        unset($this->{$name});
        $this->dispatch();
        return true;
    }
}
class Server extends Base_Infrastructure{}
class Post extends Base_Infrastructure{}
class Get extends Base_Infrastructure{}
class Session extends Base_Infrastructure{}
class Cookie extends Base_Infrastructure{
    function set($name,$value){
        $config = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['cookie'];
        $this->{$name} = $value;
        setcookie($name,$value,time()+$config['expire'],$config['path']);
    }
    function remove($name){
        $config = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['cookie'];
        unset($this->{$name});
        setcookie($name,null,time()-$config['expire'],$config['path']);
    }
}
class Files extends Base_Infrastructure{}
```

I think there is no other way unless I define every class one by one...

Comment: and why not just use $_SERVER? No one really uses $GLOBALS

Comment: same here, I favor the usage of specific variables $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, etc.

Comment: I agree, that's like using `$HTTP_GET_VARS` instead of `$_GET` now a days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!
the problem was in the php.ini file

the option

auto_globals_jit = On
should be "Off"

Answer (score 0):

check `var_dump($GLOBALS)` - maybe you had overwritten your $GLOBALS somewhere.

Comment: var_dump($GLOBALS); gives array(6) {
  ["_GET"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_POST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_COOKIE"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["PHPSESSID"]=>
    string(26) "52l9aj4ql1672jik19f1pdi647"
  }
  ["_FILES"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["GLOBALS"]=>
  *RECURSION*
  ["_SESSION"]=>
  &array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: If $GLOBALS['_SERVER'] does exists at beginning and does not exist somwhere else, you should find the line where it disappears. Maybe something like unset($_SERVER)?

Answer (score 0):

use $_SERVER and problem solved